# Algorithm (two-sum) time complexity comparison

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Relates to this leetcode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

This is my solution to 2 Sum, it takes ~45ms runtime:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int[] res=new int[2];
        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j=i+1; j<nums.length; j++) {
                
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                    res[0] = i;
                    res[1] = j;
                    return res;
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

and below is the best rated 0ms solution which beats 100% Java solutions:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        
        for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            
            for (int j = i; j < nums.length; j++) {
                
                if (nums[j] + nums[j - i] == target) {
                    
                    arr[0] = j - i;
                    arr[1] = j;
                    
                    return arr;   
                }
            }
        }
        
        return arr;
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, both of the solutions make same number of array accesses to find the result. The only actual difference is the if-condition:

`if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {`

vs

`if (nums[j] + nums[j - i] == target) {`

I am really unable to get how does this make such a big difference!!

Please clarify this ambiguity to me. Thanks :)

Comment: The one you copied doesn't work.  I think you wrote j when you meant i somewhere

Comment: @maloomeister The outer loop is `N` iterations vs `N-1` iterations. 
The inner loop `N-i` iteration in both algorithms. 

Wrong?

Comment: Then again, if leetcode's test cases all have the two indexes adjacent to each other, then the bugged code will work and will find the answer much more quickly.  Boo leetcode

Comment: On another related note, shouldn't a hashtable give better time complexity than this? If all we are looking at is time complexity i.e

Comment: Runtimes of a few ms are useless to compare speed. Use much bigger inputs so that runtime increases to at least a few seconds. Also repeat the test several times to allow the VM-optimizations to kick in.

Comment: The two algorithms search for solutions in a different order. The first will be faster if one of the target indexes are small and the other large. The second will be faster if the two indexes are close to each other. I don't think the question is answerable without test data, and the test data is secret.

Comment: It could be that the second solution terminates early by chance. Anyway, both solutions are O(N²) worst-case, which is not really acceptable. You are hinted to find a better complexity, which is possible if you first sort the array.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Much helpful :)

With clue from the comments, I prepared a test case with larger input list and that solution which was 0ms runtime, now took 134ms.

Comment: So yes, its the 'input' factor that is making the real difference, how large is the input list and how far apart are the two elements that sum up to the target number.